# Android Sqlite, How to Split Comma separated value WHERE IN Clause

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I have a query to select students with matching scores,

```
select * from student where scores in (10,20,30)
```

---

> scores => "10,27" (Comma separated string of numbers).

Scores string needs to be split into comma separated number and then needs to be checked if it is in the IN clause (10,20,30).

For ex. If,

```
scores => "10,27" => student row selected

scores => "10,20" => student row selected

score => "1,2,3" => no match
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: So you want to return those rows that have a score of 5 or 27? How is what you are looking for different from the example query you have given - with 10,20,30 replaced by 5,27?

Answer (score 1):

Probably late to the party, but may help some. You may use csv in the following way in the SQL's IN keyword. For example:

```
String args = TextUtils.join(", ", scores);

db.execSQL(String.format("select * from student where scores in (%s);", args));
```